# Exported jar problems with javafx

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to export a jar from my project using Maven but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. On the pom file, you can see all the Javafx dependencies. Maven doesn't display any warnings after creating the jar, but when I try to run it says `"Error: Could not find or load main class packagename.MAIN Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application"`.

If I try to run it with VM arguments it works but it should also work without them. I don't understand why this isn't working. Thank you all in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>prova</groupId>
    <artifactId>name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>ClientS</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.vertion>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.vertion>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+24</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Configure maven-jar-plugin to include the manifest file -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version> <!-- Adjust the version if needed -->

                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Configure javafx-maven-plugin for JavaFX -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>packagename.MAIN</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: If you're building a "standard" JAR file, then the dependencies are not included. I suggest reading the various links under the "Packaging" header of the [JavaFX tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) page. There's one about creating a "fat" JAR file (i.e., a JAR file with dependencies), but note that's not really a supported deployment strategy for JavaFX applications due to how modules work.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using an early access version of JavaFX? I recommend you stick with general, stable releases. The current latest is `20.0.2` (though version `21.0.0` should be released some time this month).

Comment: I dont understand the fact that for example I am able to include the jdbc jar inside my server's jar but it seems to not be working no matter what. Exactly the "fat" jar method seems like a workaround and not like the correct way to do things.

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: Nothing in your POM indicates you're including any JDBC _driver_ as a dependency, let alone including one in your JAR file.

Comment: Regarding so-called fat/uber/shadowed JAR files: That was a common deployment strategy for much of Java's history. Though that was also during the era of Java being preinstalled on many user machines. Nowadays, it seems the recommended way deploy Java applications to clients outside your control is as a self-contained application (e.g., via `jlink` / `jpackage`, GraalVM's native image, etc.). There are Q&As  about this that you can find via the links I mentioned previously.

Comment: No jdbc was an example. In another project of mine the exact same pom file but instead of javafx it use the jdbc drivers and it creates the jar just fine with the jdbc driver inside. Also thanks for the clarification about the "fat jar".

Comment: "_and it creates the jar just fine with the jdbc driver inside_" – Then I suspect you had a slightly different POM file. The `maven-jar-plugin` plugin does not create a fat JAR, which is what you had previously if the JDBC driver was included inside your JAR file. Typically, that's done via the `maven-shade-plugin` plugin.